# SQL Server 2008 - Use one join to get data for two columns in Table 1

Tags: sql-server, join

I have below two tables:

Table1:

```
Cparty  |Analyse1   |Analyse2
A       |   1       |   5
B       |   2       |   6
C       |   3       |   7
D       |   4       |   8
```

Table2:

```
AnalyseKey  |   Name
1           |   Apple
2           |   Pear
3           |   Orange
4           |   Banana
5           |   Fresh
6           |   Bad
7           |   Worse
8           |   Awesome
```

Is there a way to avoid **two** inner joins to get below result?

```
Cparty  |   Analyse1    |   Analyse2
A       |   Apple       |   Fresh
B       |   Pear        |   Bad
C       |   Orange      |   Worse
D       |   Banana      |   Awesome
```

My table contain like 20 different columns, Analyse1,2.3.... and the  value for the key is all found in the same table.

Comment: Why you should not have two inner joins? What is the issue of having two inner joins?

Comment: If your data was normalized you could use Pivot.  As it is currently, I believe you will need a join for each Analyse column you add.

Comment: @JoeC you can upivot and then pivot back ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can expand to the number of column you want, or use a dynamic pivot instead.

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/CSULC76672)**

```
WITH unpvt as (
    SELECT [Cparty], [Analyse], [AnalyseKey]
    FROM Table1
    UNPIVOT
       ([AnalyseKey] FOR [Analyse] IN 
          (Analyse1, Analyse2)
    )AS unpvt
), decode as (    
    SELECT u.[Cparty], u.[Analyse], t.[Name]
    FROM unpvt u
    JOIN Table2 t
      ON u.[AnalyseKey] = t.[AnalyseKey]
)
SELECT [Cparty], [Analyse1], [Analyse2]
FROM decode
PIVOT
(
MAX(Name)
FOR Analyse IN ([Analyse1], [Analyse2])
) AS PivotTable
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]